# Helm convert String to pipeline to be valid in IF check

Tags: string, if-statement, templates, pipeline, kubernetes-helm

is it possible in help templates to do :

```
{{- $kindstr := printf ".Values.%s.prop.type" "myapp }}
```

the result is valide pipeline path

and then use this in IF command?

```
{{ - if $pipelinestr "appx" }} 
...
{{- end }}
```

this is not working and not giving any failure either
i guess the parser see this as string type not pipeline object
can it be done somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is valid since helm will interpret is a string. If I understand your question properly, I think you are looking for the `index` function:

```
{{- $kindstr := (index .Values "myapp").prop.type }}
```

Keep in mind that `.Values.myapp` should exist or else it will throw an error since it will try to access a property of a `nil` object.

You can use it in the if statement as well:

```
{{- if eq $kindstr "appx" }} 
...
{{- end }}
```